# Division calculation in html not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a division calculation in an html file however it doesn't seem to work using a php or script. {{ property.listprice }} displays a number properly in the html file I have but the other items don't work. I am not sure how to make the calls...this is what I have.

```
<?php

$first_number = {{ property.listprice }};
$second_number = 2;
$sum_total = $second_number / $first_number;

print ($sum_total);

?>
```

The file ends in propertyDetails.html and this is apart of a plugin so it can't be changed. Without the function {{ property.listprice }} displays properly on its own. I am trying to write a function that basically takes that number and then divides it by 2...

Comment: what type of syntax is this `$first_number = {{ property.listprice }};`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `$first_number` must be populate with an integer. Most likely you are getting a string. Try `int(property.listprice);`

Comment: oh I see now. You're trying to access a JS property, *the wrong way*.

Comment: You're going to need AJAX if you need PHP to process numbers from JavaScript.

Comment: `{{ ...}}` is not valid php syntax. and most templating engines are designed to build HTML, not php code... exactly HOW are you executing this code?

Comment: The file ends in propertyDetails.html and this is apart of a plugin so it can't be changed. Without the function {{ property.listprice }} displays properly on its own. I am trying to write a function that basically takes that number and then divides it by 2...

Comment: double jeopardy there ^ unless you instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of possible reasons that why it isn't working, I'll start from the basic and would go to typical solution.

1. Check the extension of the file and make sure that it ends with ".php" even if you have a HTML code inside it.
2. First try "echo"ing `$first_number` and make sure that any value is coming in it or not.
3. Why don't you simply use `echo $sum_total` instead of `print` function.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: The file ends in propertyDetails.html and this is apart of a plugin so it can't be changed. Without the function {{ property.listprice }} displays properly on its own. I am trying to write a function that basically takes that number and then divides it by 2...

Comment: The problem could be here. You are trying to execute an ".html" file through ".php" parser which isn't possible but the opposite is. That is why I'm suggesting you to change the extension to ".php" instead of ".html"

Comment: Untrue ^  - Unless OP instructs Apache to treat .html files as PHP.

Comment: I don't think that OP would have done that. That's something a bit advanced.

Comment: ...which is their only option, given their only option. People need to know the tools made available to them.